# Using AWK for a variable inside a loop

Tags: bash, awk

So I get some URL's from my other team and I need to identiy a defined pattern in that URL and save the value after the pattern inside a variable.

Can this be achieved ?

```
**Input file: Just an example**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/hakuna
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/simba
```

I wrote a simple for loop for this purpose

```
for i in `cat inputFile`
do
    storeVal=awk -v $i -F"questions/" '{print$2}'
    echo "The Name for the day is ${storeVal}"
    length=`secondScript.sh ${storeVal}`
    if [[ $length -gt 10 ]]
    then
        thirdScript.sh ${storeVal}
    elif [[ $length -lt 10 ]]
    then
        fourthScript.sh ${storeVal}
    else
        echo "The length of for ${storeVal} is undefined"
done
```

Desired Output:

```
The Name for the day is hakuna
The length of for hakuna is greater than 10
Command1 hakuna executed
Command2 hakuna executed

The Name for the day is simba
Command1 simba executed
Command2 simba executed
```

And extra point to be noted.

The reason why I need to store the awk cut value in a variable is because I need to use that variable in multiple places with the loop.

Comment: What does `second value of the URL` mean? For example, what is it in <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/xxx/yyy>?

Comment: @Quasímodo I've re-edited, I took out the first line stating the second value, it was confusing, I simpliied it to a better extent.

Comment: @theborngeek : You are talking about `awk`, but your program never executes awk! The line `storeVal=awk -v $i -F"questions/" '{print$2}'` tries to execute the command `-v`, and places into the environment for this command the variable `storeVal`, which is set to the string `awk`. Likely you were thinking about something like `storeVal=$(awk ....)`

Answer (score 1):

Since it sounds like you want to run a command for every line in the input file, you can just use the built-in functionality of the shell:

```
while IFS=/ read -ra pieces; do
  printf '%s\n' "${pieces[@]}" # prints each piece on a separate line
done < inputFile
```

If you always want the last part of the url (i.e. after the last `/`) on each line, then you can use `"${pieces[-1]}"`:

```
while IFS=/ read -ra pieces; do
  variable=${pieces[-1]} # do whatever you want with this variable
  printf 'The Name for the day is %s\n' "$variable" # e.g. print it
done < inputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to extract all the string after the `questions/` bit, you can simply use shell pattern substitution for that.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    storeVal=${line##*questions/}
    echo "The Name for the day is ${storeVal}"
done < 'inputFile'
```

---

Sample input file:

```
$ cat inputFile
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/hakuna
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/simba
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/simba/lion
```

Output of script:

```
The Name for the day is hakuna
The Name for the day is simba
The Name for the day is simba/lion
```